# Are questions offering to pay for answers/help appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

Are users permitted to indicate they are willing to offer financial compensation for answers to their questions?

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "No", but I couldn't find the answer written anywhere in the FAQ.

I am referring to [Order list: Pay unpaid invoices](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29124/drupal-commerce-order-list-pay-unpaid-invoices), and any similar question.

> If it requires some coding then can offer a small fee for it if completed in short time (2-3 days).

Comment: See also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward-right-or-wrong) on *Meta Stack Overflow* gives some reasons why they should be edited out.

- There's always the possibility that the offer isn't even genuine.
- Assuming it is legit, it is essentially hiring someone to solve a problem. The place for hiring someone isn't within a question, [it is elsewhere](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

I agree with that answer that whatever the OP wants to offer, it should be done outside the site, and it should be the award for a good answer, not an incentive for answering.

On Stack Exchange, there are already bounties, which are an incentive to answer questions.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!  I also agree.